# Plot vector dynamics on unit ball

Tags: plotting

I have a unit ball and a vector with r0x, r0y and r0z ,the x,y,z components at initial time. Then they evolve to r2x, r2y and r2z as function of time. How can I show the dynamics of the three vectors on the unit ball? $\Delta$ is a parameter of choice.

```
density2=0.5{{1+0.5, 0.25},{0.25,1-0.5}};

H = -(Δ/2) PauliMatrix[3];

density2t = MatrixExp[-I*H*t].density2.MatrixExp[I*H*t];

r0x = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[1]]//FullSimplify
r0y = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[2]]//FullSimplify
r0z = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[3]]//FullSimplify

r2x = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[1]] // FullSimplify
r2y = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[2]] // FullSimplify
r2z = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[3]] // FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
density2 = 0.5 {{1 + 0.5, 0.25}, {0.25, 1 - 0.5}};
Δ = 2.
H = -(Δ/2) PauliMatrix[3];

density2t = MatrixExp[-I*H*t].density2.MatrixExp[I*H*t];

r0x = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[1]] // FullSimplify
r0y = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[2]] // FullSimplify
r0z = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[3]] // FullSimplify

r2x[t_] = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[1]] // FullSimplify
r2y[t_] = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[2]] // FullSimplify
r2z[t_] = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[3]] // FullSimplify

r0 = Norm[{r0x, r0y, r0z}]

Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r0], 
     PointSize[Large], Point[{r0x, r0y, r0z}]}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r2x[t], r2y[t], r2z[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], Axes -> True]
```

If you want to make an animation

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[Show[
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {r2x[t0], r2y[t0], r2z[t0]}}], 
 Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r0], PointSize[Large]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{r2x[t], r2y[t], r2z[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}],
{t0, 0, 10, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: ,Many thanks. How can I show the three components as arrows initially and then show how the components move about?